# How can the gRPC Python server communicate with nginx without wsgi?

Tags: python, nginx, grpc, uwsgi

I am trying to make a gRPC server in python.
When I searched it, I could have an nginx server in front of the gRPC server.
However, as far as I know, cgi such as uWSGI is required to link python applications with nginx.
gRPC can communicate without such a setting?
I want to know why.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/